# Whether Data augmentation really needed in Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am interested in knowing the **importance of data augmentation**(rotation at various angles, flipping the images) while providing a dataset to a Machine Learning problem.

Whether it is really needed? Or the CNN networks using will handle that as well no matter how different the data are transformed?

So I took a classification task with 2 classes to conclude some results

1. Arrow shapes
2. Circle shapes

The idea is to train the shapes with only one orientation(I have taken arrows pointing right) and check the model with a different orientation(I have taken arrows pointing downwards) which is not at all given during the training stage.

*Some of the samples used in Training*

[image] [image] [image] [image]

*Some of the samples used in Testing*

[image] [image]

This is the entire dataset I am using in for creating a tensorflow model.
https://bitbucket.org/akhileshmalviya/samples/src/bab50b85d826?at=master

I am wondering with the results I got,

(i) Except a few downward arrows all others are getting predicted correctly as arrow. Does it mean data augmentation is not at all needed?

(ii) Or is this the right use case I have taken to understand the importance of data augmentation?

Kindly share your thoughts, Any help could be really appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

Data augmentation is a data-depended process.

In general, you need it when your training data is complex and you have a few samples.

A neural network can easily learn to extract simple patterns like arcs or straight lines and these patterns are enough to classify your data.

In your case data augmentation can barely help, the features the network will learn to extract are easy and highly different from each other.

When you, instead, have to deal with complex structures (cats, dogs, airplanes, ...) you can't rely on simple features like edges, arcs, etc.. 
Instead, you have to show to your network that the instances you're trying to classify got an high variance and that the features extracted can be combined in a lot of different ways for the same subject.

Think about a cat: it can be of any color, the picture can be taken in different light conditions, its whole body can be in any position, the picture could be taken with a certain orientation...
To correctly classify instances so different, the network must learn to extract robust features that could be learned only after seeing a lot of different inputs.

In your case, instead, simple features can completely discriminate your input, thus any sort of data augmentation could help by just a little bit.

Comment: nessuno, I agree with your point. But the basic intuition with respect to right direction arrow use case is , the down arrow features are not fed to train the network right?. But still it predicts the down array as part of the right arrow. I am unable to relate with my intuition. What is the characteristic/features that helps to predict down arrow as right  arrow?  Or am i missing any fundamental?

Comment: First of all Thanks a lot for answering @nessuno.. So in this case as you are saying the 2 classes are highly different from each other, I agree. What if instead of a circle I train a shape similar to a downward arrow(say for example rectangle with breadth being small and height being large)? As @ user3796318 points I am unable to relate. Kindly help

Comment: Just think that a CNN learns to extract *local* features. The CNN itself doesn't know anything about the arrow direction or anything about the input seen as a whole. The convolutional filters, in the first layers specifically, just learn to extract what they see in `3x3` areas (or whatever the filter size is). Thus, if the first layer learns to extract edges, the second layer learns to combine them into lines & arcs (for example). The last layer classifies lines into the arrow and arcs into circles. @Karthik I guess that if you lower the interclass variability the problem will be harder. try!

Comment: yes, you are right the number of misclassified images(downward arrows returning as rectangle) becomes higher when I trained a model with rectangle instead of circle! with respect to the working of convolutional layer you are explaining, the last layer classifies the line as rectangle instead of arrow now for which the result is different when I trained with circle.

Comment: So from the observations now I am thinking like to predict downward arrow under arrow, I should have data augmented and given in the training set itself right. Even then now I am unsure in case of classifying rectangle and downward arrow into separate classes successfully what has to be done? Whether To increase the convolutional layer or to increase the FC layer or do you suggest any other ideas? Thanks for your help so far :)

Answer (score 0):

The task you are solving can be easily solved without any NN and even without machine learning.

Just because the problem is so simple it does not really matter whether you do a data augmentation or not. The need for data augmentation is task specific and depends on many things:

- how easy is to augment the data with preserving the ability to correctly mark the class. For image, sounds which we used to see/hear it is not a problem (we know that adding small noise to the sound does not change the meaning, rotating the lizard is still a lizard). For other things augmenting without preserving the class/value is hard (for example in Go, randomly adding a stone can change the value of the position dramatically)
- does the augmented data is drawn from the same distribution you care about. Adding random stones to Go does not work, but rotating flipping the board works and preserves distribution. But for example in a racing king game ([variant of chess](https://lichess.org/variant/racingKings)) it will not help. You can't flip the position (left <-> right), the evaluation stays the same, but it will never happen in real game and therefore drawn from different distribution and useless
- how much data do you have and how expressive is your model. The more parameters you model have, the bigger the chance of overfitting and the more is your need for data. If you train a linear regression in `n` dims, you will have `n + 1` params. You do not really need to augment this. Also if you already have 10bln data points, the augmentation is probably will not be helpful.
- how expensive the augmentation procedure. For rotating/scaling the image it is very cheap, but for other augmentation it can be computationally expensive
- something else that I forgot.